# SQL JOIN with 2 tables because data not complet

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i need help with one Statement. I have 2 tables. In one table are my data, but not completed in month 1-12. In other table I have month 1-12. I dont know how to get all my data with all month. and if there are no data for this month he should set 0.

Table1:

[image]

Table2:

[image]

I tried to use this statment but it dont work...

```
SELECT table2.produkt, table2.monat
       (CASE WHEN table2.wert IS NULL THEN table1.wert ELSE 0  END) 
FROM table2 JOIN
     table1
     ON table1.produkt = table2.produkt
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select t2.produkt, t2.monat, coalesce(t1.wert, 0) as wert
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t2.produkt = t1.produkt and t2.monat = t1.monat
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use left join

```
SELECT table2.produkt, table2.monat

       (CASE WHEN table2.wert IS NULL THEN auftrag.wert ELSE 0  END) 
FROM table2 Left JOIN
     table1
     ON table1.produkt = table2.produkt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join as opposed to a join.  That will return all the items in the left most table (table2) and only those that are linked from the other table.  That is assuming that your base table is table2

```
SELECT table2.produkt, table2.monat
       (CASE WHEN table2.wert IS NULL THEN auftrag.wert ELSE 0  END) 
FROM table2 LEFT JOIN
     table1
     ON table1.produkt = table2.produkt
```

Answer (score 0):

For your Query you can use a Left Join instead of join

SELECT table2.produkt, table2.monat
       (CASE WHEN table2.wert IS NULL THEN auftrag.wert ELSE 0  END) 
FROM table2 
LEFT JOIN table1
     ON table1.produkt = table2.produkt

With LEFT JOIN you'll return all the rows of the table you set as FROM, so you can have all the rows from the TABLE2 returning also the TABLE1 rows with a match on your LEFT JOIN Criteria (table1.produkt = table2.produkt), without your case that values would be null

Hope it can be solved your problem!